# Signature of a Permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

If the signature is s(x) we know that (A) ∀ x,y ∊ Sn s(xy)= s(x)s(y) .
Suppose we want to compute the signature of a permutation using the DCN method, My question is why do we need to have the permutation in DCN ?
Since s(x) when x is an r-cycle is (-1)^(r-1) we can use this and (A) to compute the signature.
0

DCN means disjoint cycle notation and s(x) is defined as follow : Δ = ∏ ( xj - xi) j ⪪ i , Let each permutation g in Sn permutes the variables x1 ,......., xn in the same way with 1,........., n . then g(Δ) = Δs(g) where s(g) = +1 or -1 .

Thanks for considering my question .

Comment: What DCN means ? What is your definition of $s(x)$ ? (there are several).

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It seems to me that you just answered your own question. When the permutation is in DCN you can read off the sign really quickly by the method you described. This is the answer to the question 'Why do people like to have permuations in DCN when computing the sign?'. If your question is instead: 'do you HAVE to do it in this way?', i.e. 'aren't there any other methods?', then of course the answer is 'no' and you ALSO have already answered  this yourself by giving a different way: reading off the sign by evaluating the effect of permutation $g$ on the discriminant $\Delta$.

Comment: For the second question in your comment , I agree . But my question actually was why do we need to put the permutation in DCN since we can use the first method I described  with any r-cyle , eg: (123)(536)  is the product of two 3-cycle not disjoint, then the signature is (-1)^2 ×(-1)^2 using the first method I described .

Comment: @Vincent ( sorry for the format i'm new here )

Comment: Aaah now I understand! I'll type my answer as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments I think your question is: does decomposing the permutations as a product of DISJOINT cycles have any advantage over decomposing it as ANY product of cycles when you goal is to compute sign. The answer can be yes or no depending on your perspective:

Perspective 1: I have permutation written as a product of (non-disjoint) cycles, should I recompute it into a product of disjoint cycles in order to more easily compute the sign?

Answer: NO

The formula "sign is the product of the signs of the cycles, and a cycle of length $r$ has sign $(-1)^{r+1}$" is correct whether or not the cycles are disjoint.

(You already know this)

Perspective 2: I have a permutation in the form of a black box function, i.e. for every number I know to which number the permutation sends it. I want to compute the sign via writing the permutation as a product of cycles so I can apply the formula described above. Is there any reason for writing it as a product of DISJOINT cycles specifically?

Answer: YES.

Reason: there is a very quick and easy algorithm for writing your permutation in this form. (I can edit it in if you want, but you probably already know it).

Of course there is a difference between the two answers. The argumentation for 'NO' relies on a hard mathematical fact (the formula works in both cases) the argument for 'YES' relies on a personal preference for quick algorithms that I already know over slower or more complicated or equally easy but yet unknown to me algorithms. But other people might have other preferences. So in that sense you can argue that 'NO' is the 'better' answer. But both have some merit.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thanks a lot for your time @Vincent